# send data (POST) from jquery to controller in cakephp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

Well,

The problem is that I always get the same error "anonymous function" is because when I want to send data via post these never find the Controller or the path to the Controller, I have proven with three ways to send data in the JS.

validate.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var route ="<?php echo Router::Url(array('controller' => 'soyaproductorcompras','action' => 'validate_form', 0 => $this->request->params['pass'][0], 1 => $this->request->params['pass'][1]));?>";
    $('#proveedor_carnet').blur(function(){
        $.post(route,
        { 
              field: $('#proveedor_carnet').attr('id'), 
              value: $('#proveedor_carnet').val() 
            },
            handleNmeValidation
        );
    });
    function handleNmeValidation(error){
        if(error.length > 0){
            if($('#proveedor_carnet-notempty').length === 0){
                $('#proveedor_carnet').after('<div id="proveedor_carnet-notEmpty" class="error-message">' + error + '</div>');
            }
        }else{
            $('#proveedor_carnet-notEmpty').remove();
        }
    }
});
```

here Ihave the code that I am Using for my validation the problem is the route.

first option:

```
var route ='/cake/soyaproductorcompras/validate_form';
```

second option

```
var route ='http://localhost:8080/cake/soyaproductorcompras/validate_form';
```

and the last

```
var route ="<?php echo Router::Url(array('controller' => 'soyaproductorcompras','action' => 'validate_form', 0 => $this->request->params['pass'][0], 1 => $this->request->params['pass'][1]));?>";
```

I see similar problems but do not apply, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648823/posting-to-controller-with-jquery-ajax-in-cakephp).

this is the controller validate form:

```
public function validate_form()
{    
    $this->loadModel('SoyaProductorCompra');
    $this->loadModel('SoyaProveedor');
    $this->autoRender = FALSE;
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $proveedor=$this->data['SoyaProductorCompra'][$this->params['form']['field']]=$this->params['form']['value'];
        $existe = $this->SoyaProveedor->find(
            'first',
            array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'SoyaProveedor.id'
                ),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'SoyaProveedor.id' => $proveedor
                )
            )
        );
         if(empty($existe)){
            //return false; 
             echo "no existe el usuario";
        }else{
            //return true; 
            echo "el usuario existe";
        }
    }           
}
```

error complete

```
POST http://localhost:8080/cake/soyaproductorcompras/%3C?php%20echo%20Router::Ur…pass%27][0],%201%20=%3E%20$this-%3Erequest-%3Eparams[%27pass%27][1]));?%3E 404 (Not Found) jquery.js:9666
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send jquery.js:9666
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:9211
jQuery.each.jQuery.(anonymous function) jquery.js:9357
(anonymous function) VM811 validation.js:4
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:4624
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle
```

Comment: _"anonymous function"_ is not an error (message), if at all, that's the location where an error occurred.

Comment: yes but, when I did a debug always get error in that point where never goes validate_form, I update the error complete.

Comment: This is not a valid URL for ajax request: %3C?php%20echo%20Router::Ur…pass%27][0],%201%20=%3E%20$this-%3Erequest-%3Eparams[%27pass%27][1]));?%3E

Comment: You cannot execute php code inside a javascript file, fix these issues

Comment: yes I now for these reason I explain that use before and after use this code php, and the 3 ways to try gives me the same error.

Comment: Router::connect(
        '/validate-form',
        array('controller' => 'soyaproductorcompras', 'action' => 'validate_form', 5);
    );

Then replace in javascript this:

    $.post('/validate-form',
    { 
        field: $('#proveedor_carnet').attr('id'), 
        value: $('#proveedor_carnet').val() 
    },
            handleNmeValidation
    );

Comment: hanks for the help but continuously giving me the same error.

Comment: $.post should post to your controller.

Comment: So you _always_ receive a 404, for _all_ the URLs listed above? What have you tried to debug the problem? Is your app running in debug mode? Have you tried invoking the URLs directly in your browser? How about disabling the "is ajax" check? In case you're using the Security component, have you tried to disable it? etc... no offense, but SO is not a debugging service, you'll have to do that on your own, and once you can pinpoint it down to a problem that is understandable and/or reproducible by others, SO might be the right place to ask for help.

Comment: I understand what you mean this is not a debug service clearly explain where is the problem and what is. Now you want to teach me how to debuguear okay I understand  but all that I did, reaching the conclusion that the error is in route in the post, all system is working well and this is the only jquery that is giving me problems.